# R programming - Missing values

Tags: r, na

I have an issue regarding the missing value in R.I would like to calculate the correlation between 2 fields (excluding NA in all variables)

My function is supposed to to :

- In a directory, check all the files 001.csv, 002.csv, ..., 332.csv
- Check the number of rows in each file
- If the number of rows > threshold then calculate the correlation between the 2 columns nitrate and sulfate
- return the vector_of_correlation

I tried 2 codes :

Code 1 :

```
test_correlation_na <- function(directory, threshold){
vector_of_correlation <- numeric(0)
for (i in 1:332)
 {
      temp_file=na.omit(read.table(paste(directory,sprintf("%03d",i),".csv",sep=""),header=TRUE,sep=","))
  if (nrow(temp_file) >=threshold  &     !is.na(cor(temp_file$nitrate,temp_file$sulfate)))
  {
  vector_of_correlation <-     rbind(vector_of_correlation,cor(temp_file$nitrate,temp_file$sulfate))
  }
 }
 vector_of_correlation
}
```

Code 2 :

```
test_correlation_na <- function(directory, threshold){
vector_of_correlation <- numeric(0)
for (i in 1:332)
 {
      temp_file=na.omit(read.table(paste(directory,sprintf("%03d",i),".csv",sep=""),header=TRUE,sep=","))
  if (nrow(temp_file) >=threshold )
  {
  vector_of_correlation <-     rbind(vector_of_correlation,cor(temp_file$nitrate,temp_file$sulfate))
  }
 }
 vector_of_correlation
}
```

My question is not a duplicate because i want to understand the differences between my 2 codes, which gave me different results

Comment: It looks like you got the right output. Just change `rbind` to `c`. The rbind function is used to create matrix-like objects; in this assignment you just need a regular vector.

Comment: I would say not to close this as a duplicate for two reasons, 1) the sticking points are not the same even though they are from the same question prompt, 2) This is a new user learning the ropes of R functionality, pointing them to a completely different answer to just "get the assignment done" defeats the purpose of learning. It is better to help them with their approach.

Comment: You're right Pierre. I've asked the question not to have the "assignement done" but to understand the difference. I know that one do what is needed... So it means that when i have to understand the result of the summary (if it's done on a matrix or vector).

Comment: You need a vector as an answer. Change `rbind` to `c`